# NumPy: Is there a way to perform 'shifting' on a ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Original array:

```
array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

With offset = 2 the result would be:

```
array([[ 10,  11, 12, 13],
       [14, 15, 0, 0]])
```

With offset = -2:

```
array([[ 0, 0, 8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13]])
```

Is there a way to do this other than creating multiple slices and concatenating them with `np.r_`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
def shift1d(a, offset):
    if offset == 0:
        return a.copy()

    b = np.zeros_like(a)
    if offset<0:
        b.ravel()[-offset:] = a.ravel()[:offset]
    else:
        b.ravel()[:-offset] = a.ravel()[offset:]

    return b

shift1d(a, 2)
# array([[10, 11, 12, 13],
#        [14, 15,  0,  0]])

shift1d(a,-2)
# array([[ 0,  0,  8,  9],
#        [10, 11, 12, 13]])
```

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks for catching the edge case.